# how vector space look like after applying weyl unitarian trick on finite group representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, unitary-matrices

I have a question about following theorem.

> **Theorem:** Every representation of finite group is equivalent to some unitary representation.

To prove this, we make a new inner product from original one by
$$
\langle v,w \rangle 
:= \sum_{g\in G} \bigl(\rho(g)v,\rho(g)w\bigr), 
$$
where $(v,w)$ is original inner product,
and then check that this is invariant under linear transformation by representation of group.
because this new inner product is invariant, our representation is considered to be unitary in this new vector space. on the other hand dimension of this new vector space is same as original one, these two vector space are isomorphic and hence our representation is equivalent to some unitary representation.

I was curious how this new vector space looks like.
for example i considered irreducible non-unitary representation of $S_3$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(e)&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{array}\right)\,,&
\Gamma(P_{12})&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&-1 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)\,, &
\Gamma(P_{13})&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)\,,\\
\Gamma(P_{23})&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1&0 \\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)\,, &
\Gamma(P_{123})&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&-1 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right)\,, &
\Gamma(P_{132})&=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right)\,,
\end{align}
and then applied weyls unitarian trick and observed how equidistant points transforms.

On original space these equidistant points forms circle and any reversible linear transformations should transform this to some rotated ellipse.
but what I actually observed was ellipse with some dimple.

[image]

Am I missing some thing?

Also, how can I obtain linear transformation that leads original vector space to new vector space with this new inner product.

Thanks.

Code I used to make a plot is following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#define angle parameter for unit vectors
theta = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)

#define representation matrix
reps = [np.mat([[1,0],[0,1]]),
        np.mat([[1,-1],[0,-1]]),
        np.mat([[0,1],[1,0]]),
        np.mat([[-1,0],[-1,1]]),
        np.mat([[0,-1],[1,-1]]),
        np.mat([[-1,1],[-1,0]])]

#make polar plot figure
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(polar=True)
#plot original vectors
ax.scatter(theta,np.array([1 for t in theta]),label="original circle")

inners = []
# loop for all unitvectors
for vec in [[np.cos(t),np.sin(t)] for t in theta]:
    inner = 0
    for rep in reps:
        #transform unit vector by representation matrix
        tran = rep*np.mat(vec).T
        # calculate inner product
        prod = np.dot(np.array(tran).T,np.array(tran))
        #add inner products of all represantation transformation
        inner = inner + prod
    # take sqrt to check norm of vector
    inners.append(np.sqrt(inner))

#plot result    
ax.scatter(theta,inners,c="red", label="after appling weyls trick")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1.2),loc="upper right")
```

Comment: You must have done something wrong in getting the red curve. What'd you do to end up with that graphic?

Comment: thanks for reply. what I did was take a arbitrary unit vector and plug it to inner product defined above and do it for all unit vectors in original space. I edit an code I used to plot it but i could not find where I went wrong...

Comment: I can't understand what your code is doing. But I'm getting the sense you think the unitary trick does something to the vectors themselves. Actually, the trick turns an inner product into an invariant inner product. If you start with the usual Euclidean inner product $\langle,\rangle$, then the locus of vectors $v$ with $\langle v,v\rangle_G=k$ (with $k$ a constant) will be an ellipse. In this case, the invariant inner product applied to $v=(x,y)$ yields constant times $x^2-xy+y^2$, whose level curves are indeed ellipses. What exactly is your code doing to "transform" the vectors themselves?

Comment: my code runs as follow:
1. choose an arbitrary unit vector, respect to original inner product.
 i.e. vec = (cos(t),sin(t)) so (vec,vec)=1.
2.initialize sum of new inner product. i.e. inner = 0
3.transform vec by one of the representation matrix. i.e.$trans = \Gamma(P)*vec$

Comment: 4. take inner product (trans,trans), so this is one of terms in $$\sum_{g\in G} \bigl(\rho(tran)v,\rho(tran)\bigr)$$
5.add it to inner
6. do 3-5 for all representation matrix, so this will be new inner product.
7.take square root of inner so this can be interpreted as norm of vector.
8. plot each norm respect to $\theta$

Comment: so Im doing nothing but calculating norm of all unit vectors by newly defined inner product.  
also, can you please tell me how to obtain ellipse you mentioned?
thank you for your kind help.

Comment: So, defining $v(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, you're graphing the polar equation $r(\theta)=\langle v(\theta),v(\theta)\rangle_G^{1/2}$. In other words, you're transforming a unit vector $v$ into $\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle_G}\cdot v$. But this is definitely not a linear transformation, so there's no reason to expect applying it to the unit circle would yield an ellipse!

Comment: Observe that $\langle\rho(g)v,\rho(g)v\rangle=v^T\rho(g)^T\rho(g)v$ so $\langle v,v\rangle_G=v^TAv$ where $A=|G|^{-1}\sum \rho(g)^T\rho(g)$. When I did the arithmetic I got $\langle v,v\rangle_G=\frac{4}{3}(x^2-xy+y^2)$. The locus of points $\langle v,v\rangle_G=k$ is a $45^\circ$ rotated axis-aligned ellipse; to see this, solve for $A,B$ in $x^2-xy+y^2=A(x+y)^2+B(x-y)^2$. (Note $x\pm y$, up scaling, are the scalar projections of $(x,y)$ onto the two diagonal lines $y=\pm x$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $\langle -,-\rangle$ is the Euclidean norm and the $G$-invariant inner product is

$$ \langle u,v\rangle_G:=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \langle\rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle=u^T\left(\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)^T\rho(g)\right)v $$

with norm $\|v\|_G^2=\langle v,v\rangle_G$.

Here is how I understand your graph. Parametrizing the unit circle by $v(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ ("unit" here with respect to the Euclidean norm), you graph the polar equation $r(\theta)=\|v(\theta)\|_G$. If we think of this curve as the result of applying a transformation pointwise to the unit circle, that transformation would be $T(v)=\|v\|_Gv$, which is *not a linear transformation* of $v$. Since $T$ is nonlinear, there's no expectation that applying $T$ to a circle should yield an ellipse, as there would be for linear transformations.

What is true is that for any constant $C$, the locus of points $\|v\|_G=C$ is an ellipse. Specifically, in this case I compute that $\|(x,y)\|_G^2=\frac{4}{3}(x^2-xy+y^2)$. Graphing $x^2-xy+y^2=1$ (for instance) on Wolfram|Alpha, it appears to be an ellipse with diagonal axes. Setting it equal to $a(x+y)^2+b(y-x)^2$, we get

$$ \|(x,y)\|_G^2 = \frac{1}{3}(y+x)^2+(y-x)^2. $$

Note the coordinates $y\pm x$ are, up to a scalar multiple of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the scalar projections of the point $(x,y)$ onto the diagonal lines $y=\pm x$, which are the $x,y$ axes rotated $45^\circ$.